# wordpress website showing http error 500

Tags: mysql, wordpress, google-cloud-platform, bitnami

I have a Woocommerce (Wordpress) website hosted on Google Cloud. Suddenly the website started showing "504 Gateway Timeout Error". I rebooted the VM Instance from Google Cloud (GC) Console, Suddenly GC Console starting showing permission error. 
[GC Permission Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJ7Nx.png)

Then website started  throwing

> "Error establishing a database connection"

on website and wp-admin.

Then i took remote access to files via Filezilla. When i try to modify wp-config.php it gives me write error disk full error.

Here are my disk details

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           371M  6.4M  365M   2% /run
/dev/sda1        20G   19G     0 100% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

mysql is also not working

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status
php-fpm already running
apache already running
mysql not running
```

Now the website is showing HTTP Error 500

Is there any solution to this? Have i lost the website permanently?

I want to ask is there any workaround to get the product data like name price description ?

Comment: Your disk is actually full! You must fix this problem first.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have added 20gb more to the disk.

Comment: So resize the fs to use the additional space on the disk.

Comment: @AntonDanilov i am new to this. can u guide how to do that?

Comment: Check the actual size of the disk with `fdisk -l`. Check the filesystem type - not all fs support online resize. If you have ext3/ext4 fs, you can just run `resize2fs /dev/sda1`.

Comment: I wrote an article on how to resize. Normally resize the disk and then reboot the system. This article covers the details. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-debian-9-resize-root-file-system/

Comment: I have resized disk as the it was full and was not allowing changes. now i am getting

This site can’t be reached / refused to connect.

Comment: sudo wget http://35.200.212.128
--2019-06-20 07:59:55--  http://35.200.212.128/
Connecting to 35.200.212.128:80... failed: Connection refused.

Comment: After increasing the disk size did you try restarting the services? `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start`

Comment: The connection refused error means the service isn't running.